# Why can't I access my harddrive on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a SATA harddrive that I use for my HTPC, and I plugged it into my Windows 7 box so I could quickly transfer some files over. I can see it in disk management, but the volume name is blank and the it's blank underneath the file system column.

I can't assign it a drive letter, or anything else other than delete the volume, which isn't an option since it's got my htpc's operating system on it

What gives?

Comment: What software does the HTPC run?

Comment: XBMC via XBMCbuntu

Answer (score 2):

Windows can't read ext2, ext3, or ext4 filesystems. If you formatted the disk on a Linux box, most likely it's using a filesystem Windows doesn't understand. There is an [ext IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html) for Windows. Make 100% sure the filesystem was cleanly dismounted before attempting to access it from Windows.

Comment: With this, I can see it in My Computer now, but can't access it unless I format it.

Comment: Do you know what filesystem it was formatted with? If ext4, I don't think there's any Windows solution. (And I'd be nervous modifying the filesystem with any of them.)

Comment: i believe it's ext3

Comment: @Rob: [3 Ways to Access Your Linux Partitions From Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/)